# Same Adapter obj shown multiple times, but why?

Tags: java, android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

I Made a custom Listview and Listviewadapter. Somehow the same Data is shown multiple times in my Listview, but I don't know why.

I tried to debug it, but it didn't seem to be double added.

As you can see, I controll the input of the adapter, by using .contains, but this isn't helping.

## BrodcastReceiver

```
   private BroadcastReceiver BR_BT_Device= new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
           String action_BR_BT_Device= intent.getAction();

            if(action_BR_BT_Device.equals(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND))
            {
                BluetoothDevice device = 
      intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                if (!device.equals(null)) {
                    String sDevice_Address = device.getAddress();
                    if (!(sDevice_Address == null)) {
                        if (device.getName() == null){
                            mDeviceName = "Kein Name";
                        }
                        else {
                            mDeviceName = device.getName();
                        }
                        cBT_DeviceList mDevice = new 
       cBT_DeviceList(mDeviceName, sDevice_Address);

                        if (!(cBT_popup.mBTDevice.contains(mDevice))) {
                            cBT_popup.mBTDevice.add(mDevice);

       cBT_popup.cBTDeviceListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                    }
                }
                Log.d("Resiver", "onReceive: "+device.getAddress());
            }
        }
    };
```

## Activity for Listview obj

```
    public class cBT_popup extends MainActivity {
        public static ArrayList<cBT_DeviceList> mBTDevice = new
                ArrayList<cBT_DeviceList>();
        public ListView lv_devices;
        public static cBT_DeviceList_Adapter cBTDeviceListAdapter;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.bt_popup);
            lv_devices = findViewById(R.id.lv_devices);
            cBTDeviceListAdapter = new cBT_DeviceList_Adapter(this,
                    R.layout.lrv_bt_listview, mBTDevice);
            lv_devices.setAdapter(cBTDeviceListAdapter);
            lv_devices.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
        }
    }
```

If you need more Information let me know.

If this is important: to highlight a selected item isn't possible, don't know why at the moment.

## IntentFilter for Broadcast

´´´
    IntentFilter BT_Device_filter = new
    IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);

´´´

Comment: Add your full code. When will your BroadcastReceiver be envoked?

Comment: I tried to upload full code, but Stack overvlow doesn't want me to.

Comment: In that case I can assume your onReceive is called multiple times for same BluetoothDevice.

Comment: That is possible, but ".contains" should stop this or not?

Comment: No cBT_popup.mBTDevice.contains(mDevice) will not restrict already added device, as mDevice is a newly created object, it will not match with your list items. I will give the code in answer, try once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be onRecieve is called multiple times for same BluetoothDevice.

Try this... Replace

```
if (!(cBT_popup.mBTDevice.contains(mDevice))) {
        cBT_popup.mBTDevice.add(mDevice);

        cBT_popup.cBTDeviceListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

with

```
boolean alreadyExist = false;
    for(cBT_DeviceList mBTDeviceObj : mBTDevice){
        if(mDevice.getName().equals(mBTDeviceObj.getName())){
            alreadyExist = true;
        }
    }
    if (!alreadyExist) {
        cBT_popup.mBTDevice.add(mDevice);
        cBT_popup.cBTDeviceListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Comment: It will compare received device name with all added device name.

Comment: Thank you for your help.